# Generate month in character from calendar java into a variable

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat, monthcalendar, gettime

Good day all,

I was trying to create a date variable by using Calendar java, the following is my example code:

```
long day = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat month = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM"); // not sure how to assign this value inside
cal.setTimeInMillis(day);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 000);
Date todayDate = cal.getTime();

Timestamp current = new Timestamp(todayDate.getTime());
```

However, the value of `current` I get is `2014-01-13 00:00:00.0`. I prefer to set the `01` to `Jan` instead.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Do you want a date like 01 currentMonth?

Comment: I prefer it become `2014-Jan-13 00:00:00.0` instead of `2014-01-13 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like so?

```
        long day = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat month = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss:S"); // not sure how to assign this value inside
        cal.setTimeInMillis(day);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 000);
        Date todayDate = cal.getTime();

        Timestamp current = new Timestamp(todayDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(month.format(current));
```

Yields:

> 2014-Jan-13 00:00:00:0

Please check the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more formatting options.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    long day = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss:S");
    cal.setTimeInMillis(day);     
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 000);
    Date todayDate = cal.getTime();

    Timestamp current = new Timestamp(todayDate.getTime());
    System.out.println(month.format(current));
```

Now out put:

```
    2014-Jan-13 00:00:00:0
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/e8gE9G)

Comment: Do not forget the `:S` at the end to include the millisecond, which seems to be important for the OP.

Comment: @npinti Thanks for point me out, I missed that. added to answer

Answer (score 0):

> // not sure how to assign this value inside

there you go.. ;)

```
yy = year (2 digit)
yyyy = year (4 digit)
M = month of the year
MM = month of the year (leading 0)
MMM = month of the year (short text)
MMMM = month of the year (full text)
d = day of the month
dd = day of the month (leading 0)
h = hour (1-12)
H = hour (0-23)
m = minute of the hour
s = second of the minute
S = milisecond
E = day of the week (short)
EEEE = day of the week (full)
D = day of the Year
```

Additional [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to the SimpleDateFormat class

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for current date, you do not need `currentTimeMillis()`.

Instead you can do the following to get the desired output.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate.now()                  // Determine the current date as seen in the wall-clock time in use by JVM’s current default time zone. Better to specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone.
         .getMonth()             // Get the `Month` enum object representing the month of that `LocalDate` object’s date value.
         .getDisplayName(        // Let the `Month` enum object automatically localize to generate the string of the name of the month.
             TextStyle.SHORT ,   // Specify how long or abbreviate you want the text of the name of the month.
             Locale.US           // Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to be used in localizing the name of the month.
         )                       // Return a String.
```

> Jan

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Getting the current month means determining the current date. And getting the current date requires a time zone, as for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
Month m = ld.getMonth();
```

Let the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum automatically localize the name of the month. Control abbreviation by passing a [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html).

```
String output = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.US );
```

> Apr

## Date with time

If your goal is to combine a time-of-day with your date, use `ZonedDateTime` class. You must specify a time zone to determine the first moment of the day. The day does not start at 00:00:00 on some dates in some zones.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine the first moment of the day.
```

Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp` for the purpose of generating a String. Use the `DateTimeFormatter` class, documented in many other Answers on Stack Overflow.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Or just call `ZonedDateTime::toString` to generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Indeed, do not use `Timestamp` at all. That class is intended for use with databases, and is now replaced by `Instant` as of JDBC 4.2 and later.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).